# Microservice arcitecture - netflix technology stack

Tags: netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix, netflix-ribbon

We are starting a new project. It will be based on micro service architecture. We are considering netflix technology stack for this. For developing rest services we will be using dropwizard. So far so good. After done some reading I am getting all confused. What is different use case of

- hystrix
- eureka
- ribbon

I know question is very vague right now. I will add further details as someone have doubts.

Answer (score 4):

This article has quite though explanation of Eureka and Ribbon

> Netflix Eureka - Service Discovery Server
>   Netflix Eureka allows microservices to register themselves at runtime as they appear in the system landscape.
>
> Netflix Ribbon - Dynamic Routing and Load Balancer
>   Netflix Ribbon can be used by service consumers to lookup services at runtime. Ribbon uses the information available in Eureka to locate appropriate service instances. If more than one instance is found, Ribbon will apply load balancing to spread the requests over the available instances. Ribbon does not run as a separate service but instead as an embedded component in each service consumer.
>
> Netflix Hystrix - Circuit breaker
>   Netflix Hystrix provides circuit breaker capabilities to a service consumer. If a service doesn’t respond (e.g. due to a timeout or a communication error), Hystrix can redirect the call to an internal fallback method in the service consumer. If a service repeatedly fails to respond, Hystrix will open the circuit and fast fail (i.e. call the internal fallback method without trying to call the service) on every subsequent call until the service is available again. To determine wether the service is available again Hystrix allow some requests to try out the service even if the circuit is open. Hystrix executes embedded within its service consumer.

http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/04/10/building-microservices-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-oss-part-1/

Comment: Spencer GIbb also has a very good demo application and presentation slides that go over these tools at a high level. The slides did a pretty good job breaking down each piece.
https://github.com/spencergibb/oscon2015

Comment: I constructed, for our own company but the repo is public, a very basic no-frills proof of concept using jaxrs/resteasy, ribbon interfaces and a eurekaserver. The code runs on Wildlfy 9 but it useful in general. No observers and nothing fancy. https://github.com/Bjond/ribbon-resteasy-poc